# Color mismatch in combining R,G, and B components in Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

In the following code I first convert an image to a Numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

sceneImage = Image.open('peppers.tif')
arrImage = np.array(sceneImage) # 256x256x3 array
```

Now I define a new array and put the `arrImage` in it according to the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
final_image = np.zeros((N,N,3))
final_image[...,0] = arrImage[...,0]
final_image[...,1] = arrImage[...,1]
final_image[...,2] = arrImage[...,2]
plt.imshow(final_image)
plt.show()
```

In other words, I have copy pasted R, G, and B components separately (although this could be done much easier I am doing it on purpose).

Now, the problem is that `fianl_image` and `arrImage` do not show the same image to me. The shapes look like the following:

**arrImage:**
[image]

**final_image:**
[image]

What is the problem that these 2 are not the same?

Comment: how did you display the two arrays? Looks like you have displayed a YUV image as RGB.

Comment: and what is `N` here?

Comment: `final_image = np.zeros((N, N, 3),dtype=np.uint8)`?

Comment: @Divakar It is the size of image.

Comment: Interestingly, the two pictures are perfect negatives of each other.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. That solves the problem. Could you please add it to the answer section that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)

**dtype : data-type, optional**

> The desired data-type for the array, e.g., numpy.int8. **Default is numpy.float64.**

You just need to pass the correct dtype to `np.zeros` i.e `np.uint8`:

```
 sceneImage = Image.open('peppers.tif')
arrImage = np.array(sceneImage)  # 256x256x3 array
final_image = np.zeros((N, N,  3),dtype=np.uint8)
final_image[..., 0] = arrImage[..., 0]
final_image[..., 1] = arrImage[..., 1]
final_image[..., 2] = arrImage[..., 2]

img = Image.fromarray(final_image, 'RGB')
img.save('whatever.png')
```